# How do I group all values in a pandas column that have a frequency of 2 or less

Tags: python, pandas

Here is a fictitious example:

```
id cluster
1 3
2 3 
3 3
4 1
5 5
```

So the cluster for `id` 4 and 5 should be replaced by some text.

So, I'm able to find which values have a frequency of less than 3 using:

```
counts = distclust.groupby("cluster")["cluster"].count()
counts[counts < 3].index.values
```

Now, I'm not sure I go and replace these values in my dataframe with some arbitrary text (i.e. "noise")

I think that is enough information, let me know if you'd like me to include anything else:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
In [82]: df.groupby('cluster').filter(lambda x: len(x) <= 2)
Out[82]:
   id  cluster
3   4        1
4   5        5
```

updating:

```
In [95]: idx = df.groupby('cluster').filter(lambda x: len(x) <= 2).index

In [96]: df.loc[idx, 'cluster'] = -999

In [97]: df
Out[97]:
   id  cluster
0   1        3
1   2        3
2   3        3
3   4     -999
4   5     -999
```

Answer (score 2):

```
df.cluster.replace((df.cluster.value_counts()<=1).replace({True:'noise',False:np.nan}).dropna())
Out[627]: 
0        3
1        3
2        3
3    noise
4    noise
Name: cluster, dtype: object
```

After assign it back

```
df.cluster=df.cluster.replace((df.cluster.value_counts()<=1).replace({True:'noise',False:np.nan}).dropna())
df
Out[629]: 
   id cluster
0   1       3
1   2       3
2   3       3
3   4   noise
4   5   noise
```